# Python unittest pip package

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a pip packages project with the following folder structure:

```
/mypackage
  /src
    /mypackage
      __init__.py
      ...
  /tests
    __init__.py
    test_numer1.py
    test_numer2.py
  ...
```

if I try to run my unittests with pycharm everything works just fine, all test get detected and no problem with imports. But if I try to run the unittest over the console via

> python3 -m unittest

I get the error `module named mypackage not found` everywhere where I try to do `from my package import ...`. I've tried to add/remove an `__init__.py` at all possible folders but it is still not working. I've also tried to move the tests folder in the `/src` folder, also not working. I've also tried to run the command from basically all possible folder positions still same error.

The pip package itself is working. In another project I can do

> pip install mypackage

and then also use `from mypackage import ...`

Is there something wrong in general with my project structure?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with relative imports.

`from ..src.mypackage import pyfile` in your case.

Though you'd have to put a `__init__.py in your` src`folder for it to work, methinks. Not sure why you would need a`src`directory with a python project. Might be worth it just to put the`tests`and`mypackage``` at the same level and then change all imports to

`from . import pyfile` <- This is assuming all files are in `mypackage` and at the same level in the file tree.

Comment: i think there should be a better solution, since pycharm is also figuring out the imports correctly. If i use the relative import you provided i get the error: `attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: if i just use `from src.mypackage import ...` i get the same `no module named ...` error

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an empty `conftest.py` inside `src` folder. This will add it to the `sys.path`, so in your tests directory, you should be able to import like this:

```py
from mypackage import ...
```

However, I think installing the package in editable mode (`pip install -e .`) is still a better way, because you don't need to modify the `sys.path`.

You may want to take a look at [Good Integration Practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#test-discovery).